# Dart - Limit generic constrained type to sub type

Tags: flutter, dart

i am currently working with Flutter/Dart. I want to implement a generic helper class, which puts a received input value into a generic wrapper, depending on the type.

Here the example code:

```dart
class ClassA {}

class ClassB<T> {
  ClassB(this.t);

  final T t;
}

class ClassC<T extends ClassA? {
  ClassC(this.t);

  final T t;
}

class ClassD<T> {
  ClassD(this.t);

  final T t;

  Object getWrapper(){
    final t = this.t;

    return T == ClassA?
      ? ClassC<T>(t) //<--fails
      : ClassB<T>(t);
  }
}
```

Produces:
'T' doesn't conform to the bound 'ClassA?' of the type parameter 'T'.

ClassD is the helper which produces the wrappers. For the wrapper ClassB there is no isdue, but i could not get it to work for the wrapper ClassC. As it constrains its generic type it conflicts with the generic type of the wrapper itself, although i also included a type check there to limit the type to the constrained one.

I am wondering why this won't work and how it could be adjusted to make it work.

I tried to add a type check and adjusted it in various ways like

`T == ClassA`
or
`T is ClassA`
also including the local variable t
`T == ClassA && t is ClassA`